# Command runs fine manually but when used as script it fails

Tags: python, subprocess

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import subprocess
import sys
import argparse

user = sys.argv[1]
pwd = sys.argv[2]
port = sys.argv[3]
server = sys.argv[4]
serverport = sys.argv[5]
Sslport = sys.argv[6]
Cert = sys.argv[7]
Certpass = sys.argv[8]
Certalias = sys.argv[9]

p = subprocess.Popen(
    "wlst.sh abc.py {0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7} {8}".format(
        user, pwd, port, server, serverport,
        Sslport, Cert, Certpass, Certalias),
    shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

output, err = p.communicate()
```

When I execute above script it fails with below error

```
/bin/sh: M: command not found
```

When when I process it manually in Unix shell it runs fine.

Also I passed the arguments manually and then processed with Popen then also it ran successfully.

It is only failing when I pass the arguments with format.

Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Always hand over the command to `Popen()` as list to prevent quotation problems and command injections.

Comment: are the strings you get after passing arguments manually and with format equal?

Comment: @KlausD.i tried with that also providing a list to Popen but still the same error

Comment: @OlegRybalchenko yes passing the same strings in both case. Doing this because need to combine 3 scripts in a single program which also takes the same set of arguments

Comment: did you try call instad Popen ??